# Firebase crashlytics build_id is zero and can't upload mapping file

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I can't enable firebase crashlytics in the dashboard and com_crashlytics_build_id has 00000000000000000000000000000000 values:

1. I added a new app to existing project in firebase, download json file and put it in the app folder.
2. Added:

   // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

   classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'

and

```
// Google Services Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

3. Build a project and found that app is empty in the dashboard and com_crashlytics_build_id.xml has next values:

[image]

4. Also looks like mapping file is not uploaded.
5. Tried to crash the app, but still don't see any crash in the dashboard.
6. I don't see any error while build the apk, the project build is working properly.
   **How to enable the Crashlytics?**

[image]

Comment: you need to crash application to active the crashlytics.

Comment: Already did it, crashed the app to many times

Comment: try doing crash by this throw new RuntimeException("test");

Comment: @ahmadbajwa I did the crash crash - I don't see it in the dashboard. Looks like Crashlytics is not activated. That really strange. Yesterday I did another project and Crashlytics was enabled.